# Updating Google Sheets without overwriting the existing google sheet

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets

I am writing a data frame  into google sheets

```
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def rp_webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        results= request.json
        x=json.dumps(results)
        y=json.loads(x)

df=pd.DataFrame()
data=[{'Contact':(y['contact']['urn']),
     "Created_on":(y['input']['created_on']),
     "Message":(y['input']['text']),
     "Flow_name":(y['flow']['name'])},]
danger_data=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data,index=None,columns['Contact','Created_on','Message','Flow_name'])
df=df.append(danger_data) 
def write_to_googlesheet():
            credentials_file = "onlygsheets-8356dda396762.json"
            scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
                     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
            credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentials_file, scope)
            gc=gspread.authorize(credentials)


            danger_wb=gc.open_by_key('1PGKGPA90If8956fBgfii6w_Hn1Y9lO_rfs-eKBKDD2Fp').sheet1
            set_with_dataframe(danger_wb,df)

            print(df)


        write_to_googlesheet()
```

This code is **overwriting** the data in the google sheet. How can **update** the data without overwriting the existing dataframe?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `How can update the data without overwriting the existing data?`. Can I ask you about your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I am trying to send data to a google sheet, that part works but when another user sends their data... the existing data is scrapped off and is replaced by that user's data. I would like to update the google sheet without replacing the existing data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `when another user sends their data... the existing data is scrapped off and is replaced by that user's data.`. Can I ask you about it?

Comment: @Tanaike `set_with_dataframe` doesn't update it replaces the existing df

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation and goal, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike  I have no way of sharing that data with you

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your shared Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your current situation and goal, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I whatever was on the google sheet was the output I wanted..anyway I just wanted to update that sheet with more rows instead of replacing...I also feel like there is no info I can add at this point  @Tanaike

Comment: @DarkTemplar  I saw you had a similar problem kindly assist
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526756/dark-templar